# Como encontrar o maior valor de uma matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Bem, eu tenho uma matriz 3x4 e quero saber como desenvolver um código em python pra pegar o maior valor dessa matriz.

Meu código feito até agora foi este:

```
LINHAS = 3
COLUNAS = 4
LINHA_
MatrizM = []

for i in range(LINHAS):
    MatrizM.append([])
    for j in range(COLUNAS):
        n = int(input())
        MatrizM[i].append(n)

print('=== MATRIZ M ===')
for i in range(LINHAS):
    for j in range(COLUNAS):
        print(MatrizM[i][j], end='\t')
    print()
```

O que eu não sei é como posso desenvolver um código que me mostre o maior valor dessa matriz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma condição IF dentro do repetido, ficará assim:

```
controle = 0 (0 ou algum valor da matriz)
for(...)
.
if n > controle:
controle = n
.
.
```

Vamos supor que o primeiro valor é 10, o IF vai testar se 10 é maior que 0, como vai ser TRUE a variável controle recebe 10.Vamos supor que o próximo valor é 9, quando testar novamente o resultado vai ser FALSE por que 9 é menor que 10, então o valor não vai se sobrescrever.

Como o amigo sugeriu no comentário, pode acontecer da sua matriz ter somente valores negativos, para contornar isto, a variável controle precisa receber algum valor da tabela no lugar do 0. Desta maneira não haverá problemas com números positivos e negativos.

Comment: E se todos os valores da matriz forem negativos?

Comment: Você pode fazer o seguinte, em vez de colocar controle = 0, coloque controle recebendo qualquer valor da matriz, desta maneira o if vai funcionar com qualquer valor.

Comment: Então seria interessante abordar isso na resposta e deixá-la completa :D